# MQL5 function converted to OpenCL kernel using only one core

Tags: function, opencl, mql5

I have tried to convert the MQL5 function for simple moving average to OpenCL based kernel program.
Here is what I did:
**MQL5 function**

```
void CalculateSimpleMA(int rates_total,int prev_calculated,int begin,const double &price[])
  {
   int i,limit;
//--- first calculation or number of bars was changed
   if(prev_calculated==0)// first calculation
     {
      limit=InpMAPeriod+begin;
      //--- set empty value for first limit bars
      for(i=0;i<limit-1;i++) ExtLineBuffer[i]=0.0;
      //--- calculate first visible value
      double firstValue=0;
      for(i=begin;i<limit;i++)
         firstValue+=price[i];
      firstValue/=InpMAPeriod;
      ExtLineBuffer[limit-1]=firstValue;
     }
   else limit=prev_calculated-1;
//--- main loop
   for(i=limit;i<rates_total && !IsStopped();i++)
      ExtLineBuffer[i]=ExtLineBuffer[i-1]+(price[i]-price[i-InpMAPeriod])/InpMAPeriod;
//---
  }
```

**OpenCL**

```
 #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable                          
__kernel void CalculateSimpleMA(                                        
                                int rates_total,                               
                                int prev_calculated,                            
                                int begin,                                     
                                int InpMAPeriod,                               
                                __global double *price,                        
                                __global double *ExtLineBuffer                 
                                )                                              
        {                                                                  
            int i,limit;                                                   
            int len_price = get_global_id(4);                                 
         if(prev_calculated==0)// first calculation                        
         {                                                                 
            limit=InpMAPeriod+begin;                                       
            for(i=0;i<limit-1;i++) 
               ExtLineBuffer[i]=0.0;                   
            double firstValue=0;                                           
            for(i=begin;i<limit;i++)                                       
               firstValue+=price[i];                                           
            firstValue/=InpMAPeriod;                                       
            ExtLineBuffer[limit-1]=firstValue;                             
            }                                                              
        else limit=prev_calculated-1;                                   
        for(i=limit;i<rates_total;i++)                                 
            ExtLineBuffer[i]=ExtLineBuffer[i-1]+(price[i]-price[i-InpMAPeriod])/InpMAPeriod;
        }
```

The program is working fine. But the question is I did use OpenCL so that I get to use the multiple cores of the GPU. But what I see is that I am able to consume single core only. While I tried using worker in the Execution, that kernel failed to execute. This is what going on.

I thought that there is some mistake I did while converting the function to Opencl program.
Kindly, suggest me what I missed owing to what nature I am getting through my program. I wanted to use all the cores if possible.

**EDITED**

The question is related to the conversion of the function from one language to another.

Comment: get_global_id(4)  looks incorrect, should be a number between 0 and 2 since there can only be a maximum of 3 dimensions.
Also, what is your clEnqueueNDRange parameters? e.g. what is your local size?

Comment: @Ruyk I am having the information output of the `clinfo` that I can share with you: [My Opencl Info](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/06783ca379102d2734be1982b2bad98f)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallel execution is not performed OpenCL MQL5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041120/parallel-execution-is-not-performed-opencl-mql5)

Comment: Can anyone help me out?

Comment: That get_global_id(4) is incorrect, the device reports only a maximum of 3 dimensions. The OpenCL info you linked is the platform info but is not what you are submitting for your kernel. Without knowing the actual parameters for the clEnqueueNDRange we cannot help much.